# Typereference cannot refer to container

Tags: compiler-errors, typescript

I have an error during the compilation which I don't understand.

```
declare module M {
    export interface A {
        value1: string;
    }
}

declare module M.A {
    export interface B {
        value2: string;
    }
}

declare module D {
    export interface E {
        test1: M.A[]; // works
        test2: M.A; // error TS4022 : type reference cannot refer to container 'M.A'
        test3: {[key: number] : M.A}; // same error
    }
}
```

I want to use the M.A and M.A.B interfaces in my program. Is it possible ?

```
$tsc --version
Version 0.9.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reading of the spec is correct; this is a bug in the 0.9.1.1 compiler. The code compiles without error in the 0.9.5.0 beta release ([see here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TypeScript%200.9.5%20beta))

Answer (score 1):

I have [raised a bug on Codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1944) for this issue.

The example in the language specification fails in the TypeScript playground:

```
module X {
    export module Y {
        export interface Z { 

        }
    }
    export interface Y { 

    }
}

var z: X.Y.Z; // error!
```

Comment: Yes it's a good solution.


But in the «2.2 Namespaces and Named Types» chapter of the reference : http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf (page 13 or page 20) it seems to be possible to use the same names.

But the example doesn't work.